# DbUpdateConcurrencyException error when saving record in EF Core 1.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, .net-core

I have an ASP .Net Core 1.1 Web Api using EF Core 1.1

I have a controller that gets triggered when a post is performed:

```
// POST: api/People
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostPerson([FromBody] Person person)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Person.Add(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    string uri = CreateUri(person.PersonId);
    person.Uri = uri;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.Id }, person);
}
```

As you can see, this controller adds a new Person record to the database. It then gets the newly created person's ID number to generate a URI to that person, and saves this URI back to the database. The first SaveChangesAsync() works perfectly and creates a new person record in the database. Immediately after that, the Person object is already automatically populated with the newly created Person ID. However, when I call the second SaveChangesAsync(), I get this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
>   row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for
>   information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency
>   exceptions.
>
> **Source** = "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational"
>
> **Target** = ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException

**Stack Trace:**

> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32
>   commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.MySqlModificationCommandBatch.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.MySqlBatchExecutor.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.d__54.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.d__52.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.d__35.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   InspectionsWebApi.Controllers.PeopleController.d__5.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\fabsr\Source\Repos\InspectionsWebApi\InspectionsWebApi\Controllers\PeopleController.cs:line
>   78

More specifically, this appears to be a DbUpdateConcurrencyException error.

I am the only one accessing the database or using this Web API. 
I've tried reattaching the object to the context just before the second SaveChanges:

```
...
person.Uri = uri;
_context.People.Attach(person);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
...
```

But same error. I've tried re-fetching this person just after the first SaveChanges():

```
...
person = _context.People.Find(person.Id);
person.Uri = uri;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
...
```

But same error.
I've tried this just before the second SaveChanges():

```
...
var entry = _context.Entry(person);
entry.Property(e => e.Url).IsModified = true;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
...
```

but same error...Any ideas? The backend is a MySQL Server database, and I am using the Pomelo framework to talk to the database.

Comment: After `person.Uri = uri;` try calling `_context.Person.Update(person);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anton. Unfortunately, I still get the same error after trying your suggestion :(

Comment: Have you tried reloading person before second save? The example that you gave with `Find` is not reloading because `Find` is using local cache inside DbContext. To force reloading from DB you need to use `await _context.People.SingleAsync`. You haven't shown us how your Person entity looks like. Do you have any property marked as concurency token?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Krzysztof. I tried your suggestion, but I get this error at the point of executing your suggested line:

System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: You can use a foreign key to write the index into another table at the same time. It won't write the URI though, you'll just have to do that when you read it.